# iOS Simulator with iOS 7.1 in Black Screen, Reset Content and Settings not working

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

iOS Simulator with iOS 7.1 in Black Screen, 
Tried all the following.
1.  Reset Content and Settings not working
2.  Deleting the iPhone Simulator folder
3.  Ran Reset All Simulators.scpt 
4.  Even tried to restart MAC, after doing all the above. 
But Could not resolve the issue

AppleScript Error
System Events got an error: Can’t get menu bar 1 of process "iPhone Simulator". Invalid index.

I could able to run the apps with iOS 6.1 as Device Target,

Answer (score 0):

What version of Xcode are you testing on?  Please try Xcode 6 and check ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/CoreSimulator.log and ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator//system.log for information.  Depending on system load, it can sometimes take a while to boot the simulated device.